# Angular - Runtime Insert Dynamic Module with Routes

Tags: angular, webpack, dynamic, angular-ivy

Fellow Angular Developers,

Need help to get through a restructuring of Angular Application.

Let me start with our current setup:

```
We have angular 8.1.1
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^8.1.1",
    "@angular/cdk": "^8.0.2",
    "@angular/common": "^8.1.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "^8.1.1",
    "@angular/core": "^8.1.1",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "^8.0.0-beta.26",
    "@angular/forms": "^8.1.1",
    "@angular/material": "^8.0.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^8.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^8.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^4.4.6",
    "@angular/router": "^8.1.1"
...
}
And Webpack "webpack": "^4.29.6"
And no angular.json file as we are still building using external webpack way as it started as angular2 (3-4 years old project).
```

We are still using JIT  because of legacy reasons. Currently we have 1 application with Lazy load enabled. There are many sub-applications but currently, everything is in just 1 project.

Our infra is implementing a pluggable/extendable architecture. So with this, we need to separate out the UI as well into separate applications/lib/bundle (whichever works) so we could only package the required sub-application in the package. But the need is to do this attaching and removing of sub-apps **directly without re-building or refreshing the angular app**. So basically when the angular app was built some "NewAppModule" **was not part of it**, but we want to add it in run time. And to reiterate this NewAppModule will be a big application with multiple routes and numerous components in it (~100).

We tried packing the NewAppModule into a separate chunk and loading and putting it in the route.config:

```
Feature Module:

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'other1', component: FeatureComponent1 },
  { path: 'other2', component: FeatureComponent2 },
  { path: 'other3', component: FeatureComponent3 },
...
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes),...],
  exports: [RouterModule],

})
export class FeatureModule { }

Webpack:

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        'polyfills': './src/polyfills.ts',
        'vendor': './src/vendor.ts',
        'app': './src/main.ts',
        'feature': './src/feature/feature.module'
    },
...
```

Main Application

```
Login Routes:
export const loginRoutes: Route[] = [
    {
        path: 'logincontroller',
        component: LoginComponent
    },
    { path: '**', redirectTo: '/' }
];

App Module:
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        HttpClientModule,
        BrowserAnimationsModule,
        LoginModule,
        CoreModule.forRoot(),
        RouterModule.forRoot(loginRoutes, { useHash: true, preloadingStrategy: CustomPreloader })
    ],
    declarations: [
        AppComponent
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})

export class AppModule {
    public static config: ConfigService;
}


export const homeRoutes: Route[] = [
  {
      path: 'home',
      component: HomeComponent,
      canActivate: [AuthGuard]
  },
  {
      path: 'feature',
      loadChildren: () => fetch('feature.js')
      .then(response => response.text())
      .then(source => {
          const obj = eval(source);
          return obj.FeatureModule;
      }),
      ,canActivate: [AuthGuard]
  }
];

];
```

In the end we are able to see the module, added to this.router.config **but the routes are incorrect**, the routes point to loginRoutes.
Also even if this work we need help to go beyond this as currently, I am assuming that I know the module name. What we need is runtime module patching without even knowing the name of the module.

```
{
      path: 'feature',
      loadChildren: () => fetch('feature.js')
      .then(response => response.text())
      .then(source => {
          const obj = eval(source);
          return obj;   // This is directly the module that we need as we do not know the name
      }),
      ,canActivate: [AuthGuard]
  }
```

We also tried updating the router.config and router.resetConfig:

```
let newRoute =   {
      path: 'feature',
      loadChildren: () => fetch('feature.js')
      .then(response => response.text())
      .then(source => {
          const obj = eval(source);
          return obj.FeatureModule;
      }),
      ,canActivate: [AuthGuard]
  };
this._router.resetConfig([...this._router.config, route]);

This fails completely, no module loading, nothing.
```

All the IVY tutorials that we are seeing are to Dynamically Import **Components**, but not importing and attaching a **complete Module(with Routes) at runtime**.

Is something like this even possible in angular, if yes what could be done and where are we going wrong (are we building the feature.js incorrectly)?

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you very much.